# В поисках примеров реализаций API Яндекс.Деньги для C#

Tags: c#, yandex-money

Разыскивается примеры реализаций с использованием API Яндекс.Деньги для C# https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-money-sdk-net

Примеров как не странно нет, есть один, для линкпада, но и он какой-то не информативный, и не колерирует с кодом из описания SDK. Вот этот https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-money-sdk-net-sample/blob/master/Net45/api.sdk.sample.linq

Поделитесь примерами использования. Заранее спасибо.